# Retrofit Android : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, observable

Similar questions were asked before. But none of them worked for me.
I am trying to return an observable, to which a subscriber is listening.
Everytime the subscriber's onError() method is being called with **"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $"** this error.

Here is my code :

```
public Observable<List<String>> getPlaces() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(Urls.BASE_URL)
        .build();
    RetroFitInterface service = retrofit.create(RetroFitInterface.class);
    return service.getPlaces();
}




public interface RetroFitInterface {

    @Headers({
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Content-Type: application/json"
    })
    @GET(Urls.GET_POPULAR_LOCATIONS_URL)
    Observable<List<String>> getPlaces();
}
```

HERE IS A JSON RESPONSE :

```
{
    "locations": [
        "location1",
        "location2",
        "location3",
        "location4",
        "location5",
        "location6",
        "location7",
    ],
    "success": true
}
```

This is how I am subscribing the subscriber.

```
getPlaces().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Observer<List<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Search result onCompleted()!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Search result onError()! " + e.toString());
                    }

                @Override
                public void onNext(final List<String> result) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "This is never called.");
                }
            })
```

Comment: List<String> But the response is the json object that content the json array. I think you need to use the pojo pattern. Use GSON fro json to object array list mapping. let me know if you did not get my point.

Comment: Do you know json basics? No! Learn it and the exception will be obvious.

Comment: @BhavdipPathar a help from you would be better.

Comment: Please post the code for `RetroFitInterface`.

Comment: @CommonsWare it is already there

Comment: My apologies. `RetroFitInterface` is expecting a list of strings, and that is not what your JSON is. Your JSON is a JSON object, that happens to contain a list of strings, among other attributes.

Comment: @CommonsWare correct the response seems like json object. I think it would be object of class (Response class) see my answer suppose to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi First of all you need to convert the json response into POJO. To do this I used this [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) for generate the POJO class.

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class LocationResponse {

@SerializedName("locations")
@Expose
private List<String> locations = new ArrayList<String>();
@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
private Boolean success;

/**
* 
* @return
* The locations
*/
public List<String> getLocations() {
return locations;
}

/**
* 
* @param locations
* The locations
*/
public void setLocations(List<String> locations) {
this.locations = locations;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The success
*/
public Boolean getSuccess() {
return success;
}

/**
* 
* @param success
* The success
*/
public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
this.success = success;
}

}
```

Put this class in appropriate package you have.  In next step I have update your `RetroFitInterface` interface see blow :

```
public interface RetroFitInterface {

    @Headers({
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Content-Type: application/json"
    })
    @GET(Urls.GET_POPULAR_LOCATIONS_URL)
    Observable<LocationResponse> getPlaces();
}
```

Finally, This is how your should subscribing the subscriber.

```
getPlaces().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Observer<LocationResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    }

                @Override
                public void onNext(final LocationResponse result) {
                    // your result is here
                    if(result.getSuccess()){
                            //result.getLocations();
                    }
                }
            })
```

Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: If you do not want to use the Jackson annotation you can remove it.

Comment: Are you able yo understand this

Answer (score 3):

Currently you try to deserialize the json to `List<String>` type. But `List<>` is represented in json like this: `[object1, object2, object3]`. Your json, on the other hand, is in fact an object, which *contains* the list.

```
{
    "locations": [
        "location1",
        "location2",
        "location3",
        "location4",
        "location5",
        "location6",
        "location7",
    ],
    "success": true
}
```

The POJO (java class) that would be equivalent to above json looks like this:

```
public class LocationsResponse {

  List<String> locations;
  String success;

}
```

So to answer your question, you need to create `LocationsResponse` class and use **it** as your response type:

```
public interface RetroFitInterface {

    @Headers({
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Content-Type: application/json"
    })
    @GET(Urls.GET_POPULAR_LOCATIONS_URL)
    Observable<LocationsResponse> getPlaces();
}
```

Comment: I had to add @SerializedName("locations") to get this working.

Comment: afaik gson doesn't require `@SerializedName` if java field has the same name as in json, but okay